# PHP special regular expression pattern to match URLs after a specific string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to develop a word counting application that supports .pdf, .docx, .doc, .txt, ..etc documents and I was able to read .doc files with PHP and load the plain text to a variable.

I'm using following code to remove extra white spaces of the string.

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str));
```

My issue is: Word documents with hyperlinks are phrasing as `Some dummy text here.. HYPERLINK "http://domain.com/directory/page" other dummy text is here..`

So I want to remove that `HYPERLINK "http://domain.com/directory/page"` part or replace with a space or something.

Since I'm not a regular expression expert, I'm looking for help to solve this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HYPERLINK "http://domain.com/directory/page" will be matched by:

```
HYPERLINK "[^"]*"
```

Hyperlink, then quote, then anything but quote, then quote.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer It worked for me. I used `/ HYPERLINK "[^"]*" /` because the part, I wanted to remove got two spaces before and after the string.